# Xamarin android 13.0 crash on splashscreen only for certain users (JavaProxyThrowable)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, crash, android-splashscreen

I have a serious bug I can't seem to fix or debug correctly. The app keeps crashing for all our customers on the splashscreen on android 12 or above, while it works for me personally, below android 12 (with simulators and my own phone) and above 12 (with simulators). Sadly the Google Play Store only allows app bundles with SDK version 12 or above, which generates this crash.

The users see the splashscreen really fast and then it crashes immediately. It's on the onCreate method of the MainActivity, but I've tried many things and can't seem to find it.

If anyone knows a way to reproduce this locally, knows anything about this crash or can point me in the right direction then that would be really awesome!

I already followed a tutorial on how to make a new Android 13 splashscreen, still the app crashes on the same way.

**Google Play Console Crash Report:**

```
Exception android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable:
  at crc647e6e9d558d510f83.MainActivity.n_onCreate (MainActivity.java)
  at crc647e6e9d558d510f83.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:40)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8591)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8570)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1384)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4150)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4325)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2574)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:226)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:313)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8757)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:571)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```

(from what I can find this is a general error that shows up because the app crashes before a correct error can be send, and I don't know how to change to code for it to show the correct error)

Also when adding or removing code it still throws the error on the row 40. So I can't see which part throws the error.

**This is what the MainActivity looks like currently:**

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

This is from a new test project I made, still crashes the app. This is code generated by the Xamarin framework in Visual Studio.

**Things I have tried:**

- Made users reinstall the app multiple times
- Made users delete the app and install again
- Made users update the app
- Made users remove the local cache of the app
- Made the android 13 splashscreen
- Updated all the tools used, except still use NetStandard2.0

  - got a lot of errors when trying to update to newer NetStandard6.5
- Looking for the JavaProxyThrowable error

  - also tried a TryCatch but then it hangs on the splashscreen without doing anything

**This is the software I am using:**

- Updated Visual Studio 2022
- Nexus 5X API 33 (Android 13.0 - API 33) simulator

  - Works perfectly on this simulator (no idea how with these crashes)
- Nexus 5X Pie 9.0 - API 28 (Android 9.0 - API 28) simulator (also works)
- My own samsung android phone with low android version (also works)
- Xamarin Essentials version 1.7.5 (newest)
- Xamarin Forms version 5.0.0.2578
- Xamarin CommunityToolKit version 2.0.6

Comment: My first thought is that it isn't the splash screen itself, but something that happens when try to load app. I would make a release without a splashscreen, find out if that crashes for users. But if it isn't the splash screen, then your test app should have worked. I don't have any other suggestions.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve yea the weird thing is that everything works for me fine, even if I install it through the playstore. But for everyone else it crashes :( it would be really nice to have a better crash log but I don't know how to fix that sadly

Comment: Do you have any other `crashlytics` in your App like Appcenter crashlytics?
Try to add it & check for detailed crashed report.
If you already have it, please share that report with device details as well

Comment: There is a related issue on Github: [Problem with SplashScreen](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/15635).

Answer (score 0):

Update: apparently it was something in the code that loads when a user already has a cookie from the last app. Because we took an older version and build that with android 13 and that one works. Very disappointing these error are not clearly shown in the playstore developer enviroment. That threw me off that it could be a splashscreen related error. I will take a look at crashlytics to have a better log with errors. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Glad you solved this issue! You could accept your answer which could help others with similar issue. Thanks!